# How to extract adjusted R squared in vars package?

Tags: r

This question is highly correlated with the question from this link. [How to extract p-value in var package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889205/how-to-extract-p-value-in-var-package)

I just would like to take adjusted R squared from VARS package..

Even though there is a similar question, I don't have any idea to modify to take adjusted r square.. please help me.

I just followed previous example.

```
  library(vars)
  symbols=c('^N225','^FTSE','^GSPC')
  getSymbols(symbols,src='yahoo', from="2003-04-28", to="2007-10-29")
  period="daily"
  A1=periodReturn(N225$N225.Adjusted,period=period)
  B1=periodReturn(FTSE$FTSE.Adjusted,period=period)
  C1=periodReturn(GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted,period=period)
  datap_1<-cbind(A1,B1,C1)
  datap_1<-na.omit(datap_1)   
  datap_1<-(datap_1)^2
  vardatap_3<-VAR(datap_1,p=3,type="none")
  summary(vardatap_3)
```

Then the summary can be presented like..

```
      VAR Estimation Results:
  ========================= 
  Endogenous variables: N225, FTSE, SP500 
  Deterministic variables: none 
  Sample size: 1055 
  Log Likelihood: 23637.848 
  Roots of the characteristic polynomial:
  0.8639 0.6224 0.6224 0.5711 0.5711 0.5471 0.5471 0.4683 0.4683
  Call:
  VAR(y = datap_1, p = 3, type = "none")
  Estimation results for equation N225: 
  ===================================== 
  N225 = N225.l1 + FTSE.l1 + SP500.l1 + N225.l2 + FTSE.l2 + SP500.l2 + N225.l3 +        FTSE.l3 + SP500.l3 
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  N225.l1   0.03436    0.03116   1.103    0.270    
  FTSE.l1   0.47025    0.06633   7.089 2.48e-12 ***
  SP500.l1  0.60717    0.07512   8.083 1.74e-15 ***
  N225.l2   0.14938    0.03057   4.886 1.19e-06 ***
  FTSE.l2  -0.05440    0.06744  -0.807    0.420    
  SP500.l2 -0.09024    0.07782  -1.160    0.246    
  N225.l3   0.16809    0.02924   5.749 1.18e-08 ***
  FTSE.l3   0.04480    0.06597   0.679    0.497    
  SP500.l3 -0.01007    0.07941  -0.127    0.899    
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  Residual standard error: 0.0002397 on 1046 degrees of freedom
  Multiple R-Squared: 0.3099,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.304 
  F-statistic:  52.2 on 9 and 1046 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 2):

Adjusted r squared values can be accessed in output of function `summary()` and list element `varresult`. `varresult` contains summary tables for each of daily returns.

```
> lapply(summary(vardatap_3)$varresult, "[", "adj.r.squared")
$daily.returns
$daily.returns$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.3039812


$daily.returns.1
$daily.returns.1$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.3201587


$daily.returns.2
$daily.returns.2$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.1972104
```